# Swift: Initializing data and sending it to a different controller

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I have a tableview with a list of users. By selecting one of the users, I can load their user profile in a different controller, including their personal information. Working as intended.

I also have a swipe gesture that let's admins edit or delete those users. I am currently trying to send the user data to my "Edit user" controller by selecting the edit button. Swift is giving me the following error: ***Constant 'student' captured by a closure before being initialized***

**Segue to my user profile controller**

```
class Student: NSObject {
    var profileImage: String
    var firstName: String

init(profileImage: String, firstName: String) {
    self.profileImage = profileImage
    self.firstName = firstName
  }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let student: Student
    showUserprofileDetail(student: student)
}

func showUserprofileDetail(student: Student) {

    let detailViewController = UserProfileController()
    detailViewController.student = student

    present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**In my User Profile Controller I load the data by using:**

```
var student: Student? {
        didSet {
             if let profileImage = student?.profileImage {
                 profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: profileImage)
             } 

            if let firstName = student?.firstName {
                 nameLabelView.text = firstName
             }
    }
```

**Below the swipe function to edit users.**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    // Edit student
    let student: Student

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in

        tableView.isEditing = true

        self.editUserProfileDetail(student: student)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return [edit]
}

func editUserProfileDetail(student: Student) {

    let detailViewController = EditStudentController()
    detailViewController.student = student

    self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

**New problem:**
All the data is correctly being pushed to the new controller, but only the profile image is visible. I also want the data to be pushed to all of my textfields. My textfields are custom classes in a tableview. How do I access those textfields?

```
let editStudentTableViewController = EditStudentInfoController()

    var student: Student? {
        didSet {
            if let profileImage = student?.profileImage {
                profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: profileImage)
            }

            if let firstName = student?.firstName {
                editStudentTableViewController.editStudentFirstNameTextField?.text? = firstName
            }
        }
    }

 lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile_default")
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

// MARK: Custom cells
class EditStudentFirstNameCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let editStudentFirstNameTextField: UITextField = {
    let editStudentFirstNameTextField = UITextField()
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.placeholder = "First Name"
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.textColor = .red
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    return editStudentFirstNameTextField
}()

func setupViews() {

    addSubview(editStudentFirstNameTextField)

    editStudentFirstNameTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    editStudentFirstNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
}
}
```

Comment: You are never initializing the Student object. Where are you giving student its name and profile image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign selected student to your student object before calling

```
showUserprofileDetail(student: student)

                  or

self.editUserProfileDetail(student: student).
```

Let say your array of student is **arrayStudents[Student]** that you use in table datasource to display info of student in table. Replace your line of code:

```
let student:Student
```

with

```
let student = arrayStudents[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Oh, I guess it only worked for my profile image, which is directly accessible. I also want to put the pushed data, like first name in one of my textfields. 

The problem is that my textfields are custom classes in a tableviewcontroller. How can I access those fields so that I can assign pushed data to each field?

Comment: In cellForRow data source of table you need to assign first name value. Let say your textfield outlet is textName. Then cell.textName.text = self.student.firstName.

Comment: Great! This seems to work. The last problem is that I my controller has a topview and a bottomview. The textfields are in my bottomview and my profileimage is in my topview. When I segue, I segue to my bottomview, which makes my profileImage inaccessible. How do I split this information?

Comment: Take profile image in table header so it would be accessible even you scroll till bottom of table